# Why does my iPhone Spotlight (Springboard) search show a little poop emoji in the corner?

Tags: ios, emoji, spotlight

It's kind of cute, but why is it doing this and how can I change it?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS shows the folder name when you search for an app that's stored within a folder as opposed to lying on the springboard main screens.

Any chance someone punked you by making a clever named folder and placing these exact apps inside that folder?

You can be sure your phone is fine by making a folder and controlling which apps are stored in that folder as well as the name of that folder. Searching for those apps should show the folder name of your choosing.